# Separate a combined dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
train_df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/cat-in-the-dat/train.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/cat-in-the-dat/test.csv')
all_df = train_df.append(test_df, sort=False)
```

How to separate `all_df` back into `train_df` and `test_df`?

Comment: My apologies, I meant that if I were to do operations on ```all_df```

Answer (score 1):

`train_df` and `test_df` are still in memory, so you can use them as is, no need to split.

If the goal is to do some manipulations on the combined frame then separate afterwards (`combine - apply - split`) then use `concat`, a more versatile version of append, which supports the `keys` argument. `.loc` now allows you to select each one separately.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
train_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (3, 2)))
test_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (3, 2)))

all_df = pd.concat([train_df, test_df], sort=False, keys=['train', 'test'])
#         0  1
#train 0  3  7
#      1  8  6
#      2  9  2
#test  0  8  8
#      1  2  6
#      2  2  4

test = all_df.loc['test']
#   0  1
#0  8  8
#1  2  6
#2  2  4
```

Answer (score 0):

if you save the number of row in your train_df as `n = train_df.shape[0]`

you can restore it by

```
train_df = all_df.loc[:n,]
test_df = all_df.loc[n+1:,]
```

please note that the indexing in pandas are inclusive as opposed to numpy.